# Get top highscores AND scores 3 next and previous after you

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have a `users` table where I can also this user score. So that means a user can have only one highest score. What I'd like to achieve is to query the top 10 high scores from all user and also the 5 previous and 5 next scores of the current user.
SQLFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/466d0/5
Currently I have a query which selects all users, order descending by high score and also gives a row number of each user, so it's sorted by the score. The working query for that is following:

```
SELECT u.id, u.score,
        @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS POSITION
FROM    b_users u
JOIN    (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
ORDER BY u.score DESC , u.id ASC
```

The ouput is correct

```
| ID | SCORE | POSITION |
|----|-------|----------|
|  5 |   500 |        1 |
| 20 |   433 |        2 |
| 14 |   432 |        3 |
| 18 |   350 |        4 |
| 19 |   320 |        5 |
| 16 |   201 |        6 |
| 17 |   150 |        7 |
| 12 |    90 |        8 |
| 23 |    90 |        9 |
| 11 |    70 |       10 |
| 22 |    70 |       11 |
| 10 |    60 |       12 |
|  9 |    50 |       13 |
| 21 |    40 |       14 |
|  4 |    12 |       15 |
|  3 |    10 |       16 |
|  8 |    10 |       17 |
| 13 |    10 |       18 |
| 24 |    10 |       19 |
| 15 |     8 |       20 |
|  1 |     5 |       21 |
|  2 |     3 |       22 |
|  6 |     3 |       23 |
|  7 |     2 |       24 |
```

Once again, SQLFiddle for that is http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/466d0/5
Now I'm stuck on how to extend this query so that it only outputs the top 10 position and for example if my ID is 8 (position 17) then it also outputs positions from 12 to 22.

Comment: I don't understand your question, the query you want and the conditions. I don't understand your last sentence.

Comment: @kmas currently I get all the highscores. But I need top 10 highscores PLUS the 5 highscores that are before and after specific user id

Comment: Wow, I'd hate to be somebody who signed up late - you're automatically demoted in rankings!  Actually, you probably need to keep `u.id` in the `ORDER BY`, to keep your results stable; what you should do, though, is only add 1 to the ranking if the score is different (I don't know enough about this syntax to know how to do that, or even if it's possible...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping it in an outer query, like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT u.id, u.score,
        @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS POSITION
  FROM    b_users u
  JOIN    (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
  ORDER BY u.score DESC , u.id ASC) origQuery
WHERE origQuery.position <= 10
   OR (origQuery.position >= (17 - 5) AND origQuery.position <= (17 + 5))
```

Comment: oh i'm still trying to improve the query to get this number 17. First I get the user id from the application as a parameter and then I need to get the position of this user id. In this example case the user id is 8 and his position is 17. How to improve the query so i get to know dynamically the position 17 ?

Comment: It should be something `SELECT origQuery.position WHERE origQuery.id = 8` but this query is not semantically correct

Comment: @Skyzer That is how I would probably do it, wrap that next query in parens and it should work. However, this is getting kind of ugly and performance might start to suffer. You may be better off using a procedure/function or doing some of this work on your backend (PHP or whatever you are using). I'm not sure what your working conditions are though